# NicEdit inserts multiple `<p>` tags When adding 'paragraph' formatting to multiple lines of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, nicedit

NicEditor inserts multiple `<p>` tags When adding 'paragraph' formatting  to  multiple lines of  text instead of just one set of `<P>` tags .. Example the below two lines of text

this is some dummy text
this is some dummy text

on selection and application of 'paragraph' formatting gets converted into 
`<p>this is some dummy text</p>`
`<p>this is some dummy text</p>`

instead of correctly as 
`<p>this is some dummy text`
`this is some dummy text</p>`

Please help..

Comment: Just learn to write your own HTML & CSS. You will save so much more time and effort for putting a little in the beginning.

Comment: i am talking about an inline content editor known as nicedit..
http://nicedit.com/ and its issue